# Which of the following statements is/are correct about a real-valued bounded function in $\mathbb{R}^2?$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Let $f$ be a real-valued bounded function in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that for all real $t,$ the functions $g_t(y)=f(t,y)$ and $h_t(x)=f(x,t)$ are non-decreasing. Then which of the following is/are correct?

1. $f(x,x)$ is non-decreasing.
2. $f$ can have uncountable number of discontinuities.
3. $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(+\infty,+\infty)} f(x,y)$ exists.
4. $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(+\infty,-\infty)} f(x,y)$ exists.

Option $1$ seems correct to me since $f$ is non-decreasing in each co-ordinate.

For 2) let $f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{align}
0, & \mbox{ if }~ x\leq0 \mbox{ or } y\leq0\\
1, ~& x>0\mbox{ and y>0}\end{align}\right.$

Then $f$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2,$ is non-decreasing and is discontinuous at each point on x-axis as well as on y-axis. So option 2) is also correct.

I am thinking that 3) and 4) should also be correct since $f$ is given to be bounded. However, I am not sure.

Comment: You should show more thinking. We can answer, but most users don't want to answer a blank post. E.g. you must have some ideas about 3), 4), and if you've been asked about 2) you've probably handled a similar case in class... so share all of the above

Comment: @FShrike I have shared what I was thinking.

Comment: Your example for 2. is incorrect, as $g_{-1}(1)=f(-1,1)=1>0=f(-1,0)=g_{-1}(0).$ A correct example is f$(x,y)=0$ if $(x\le 0\lor y\le 0)$, and $f(x,y)=1$ if $(x>0\land y>0).$

Comment: For 1., if $x<y$ then $f(x,x)=g_x(x)\le g_x(y)=f(x,y)=h_y(x)\le h_y(y)=f(y,y).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks for the correction. I can see your example also rules out option 4). Can I say option 3) is correct ?

Comment: Concerning $4.$ you can take a function of the form $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$ where $g$ is strictly increasing, for example $g(t)=\arctan t.$ Then $f(x,-x)=g(0)$ and $f(x+1,-x)=g(1).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option $3.$ is correct.  For $x\ge x_0$ and $y\ge y_0$ we have
$$f(x,y)-f(x_0,y_0)=[f(x,y)-f(x,y_0)]+[f(x,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)]\ge 0\ (*)$$
Denote $A=\displaystyle\sup_{x,y}f(x,y).$ We are going to show that  $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (\infty,\infty)}f(x,y)=A$$
Let $\varepsilon >0.$ Then there exist $x_0,\ y_0,$ such that
$$f(x_0,y_0)\ge A-\varepsilon $$ Then
for $x\ge x_0,\ y\ge y_0,$ in view of $(*)$, we obtain
$$A-\varepsilon \le f(x_0,y_0)\le f(x,y)\le A$$ Hence $$A-\varepsilon\le f(x,y)\le A,\quad x\ge x_0,\ y\ge y_0$$
This concludes the proof of the claim.

Comment: Nice proof. I thought it as : $f(x,x)$ is non-decreasing and bounded, so by monotone convergence theorem, $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to\infty}f(x,y)$ must exist.